# How do I create a new activity in Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio to version 3.5, and now the new activity option in the context menu is missing.

[image]

In Android Studio 3.1, following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#CreateActivity), I was able to create a new activity by right clicking the **app** folder in the **Project** window and selecting **New > Activity > Empty Activity**.

How can I create a new activity in Android Studio 3.5?

Comment: strange, it's there for me. what about File -> New -> Activity -> Empty Activity? and it's better to wait for your current build, indexing to be finished then trying. another question is have you setup the sdk? if you run your app does it work?

Comment: Wait for the project to sync then try to create a new activity, if the option is not appearing further. Go-to File -> Invalidate caches & restart.

Comment: You are right. It was not showing because my gradle sync failed.

Answer (score 0):

click on **app** > **res** > **layout** > Right Click on layout. After that Select **New** > **Activity** and choose your Activity as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your project still indexing your project files, at this phase, you can't create activities or java files until it finishes.

[image]

After the indexing is over, you can normally create your activity using **New > Activity > Empty Activity**

This also the same whenever you open an existing project, below is from mine where I can't create java class until it finishes.

[image]